# Calculate probablity of scoring 79 runs in card cricket match

Tags: probability, permutations

I am playing a game of cricket with 2 teams with cards

Team A and Team B

Wickets or OUT - max 5 per inning

Overs 5 per inning (30 balls- each over having 6 balls)

Total 2 innings 1 per team.

We have possible outcome score per ball is 
0, 1, 2 , 3, 4, 6, OUT
Which is 7 total cards, each card appears 10 times in deck.
Per inning available cards 
7*set of 10= 70 cards in deck

Note:If 5 OUT before 30 cards drawn inning stops for that inning at same score.

Ex

Ie..first 6 balls  is 6, 6, 4, 4, 0 , OUT

We left with 64 cards
8 x 6s
8 x 4s
9 x 0s
9 x OUTs
10 x 1s
10 x 2s
10 x 3s

Game starts with picking 30 cards 1 by 1 without replacement or less if 5 wickets fall

How do I calculate probability that team scores exactly 79 runs.